# How to Know the lastVisbile row in wpf toolkit datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

i have datagrid which has 200 rows of data. i need to display the records in 4 monitors.
monitor resolutions may be different. so, i need to display the records in such a way that suppose 40 records can fit in first monitor and the i need to take the remaining records into the second monitor like that.

how i can know the last visible row in the screen.so that i can take the count and push the remaining data to next monitor.

or Any other approach also will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy to do! A few months back I wrote a utility method for a Windows Phone 7 application that enumerates the items that are currently visible within an ItemsControl:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enumerates all the items that are currently visible in an ItemsControl. This
    /// implementation works for both virtualized and non-virtualized panels.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetItemsInView(this ItemsControl itemsControl)
    {
        // find the panel that hosts our items - this is 'cached'
        // using the ItemsControl.Tag property to minimize visual tree
        // navigation
        Panel itemsHostPanel = itemsControl.Tag as Panel;
        if (itemsHostPanel == null)
        {
            itemsHostPanel = itemsControl.Descendants<Panel>()
                                            .Cast<Panel>()
                                            .Where(p => p.IsItemsHost)
                                            .SingleOrDefault();
            itemsControl.Tag = itemsHostPanel;
        }

        VirtualizingStackPanel vsp = itemsHostPanel as VirtualizingStackPanel;
        if (vsp != null)
        {
            // implementation for virtualizing lists
            return GetItemsInView(itemsControl, vsp);
        }
        else
        {
            // implementation for non-virtualizing lists
            return Enumerable.Range(0, itemsControl.Items.Count)
                          .Select(index => itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index))
                          .Cast<FrameworkElement>()
                          .Where(container => container.GetRelativePosition(itemsControl).Y + container.ActualHeight > 0)
                          .Where(container => container.GetRelativePosition(itemsControl).Y < itemsControl.ActualHeight);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the items in view for a virtualizing list
    /// </summary>
    private static IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> GetItemsInView(this ItemsControl itemsControl, VirtualizingStackPanel vsp)
    {
        // iterate over each of the items in view
        int firstVisibleItem = (int)vsp.VerticalOffset;
        int visibleItemCount = (int)vsp.ViewportHeight;
        for (int index = firstVisibleItem; index <= firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + 2; index++)
        {
            var item = itemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as FrameworkElement;
            if (item == null)
                continue;

            yield return item;
        }
    }
```

This *should* work for a WPF DataGrid. As you can see the implementation depends on whether the view is virtualized or not.

Note, this code is part of the WP7Contrib project, and [can be seen here](http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/70091#1502035). It has dependencies on a few other utility / extension methods.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. coline, so i need to place the grid in the itemscontrol. i am pretty new bee to WPF. if you have any example how we can use this extension class that will be more helpful.